# Intel Compiler Openmp SIMD AVX512 performance problem

Tags: openmp, simd, icc, avx2, avx512

I am learning the openmp simd part and wrote a small program to test the performance of simd.

System is centos7.The cpu I am using is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6258R CPU @ 2.70GHz, which I believe supports avx512.
This my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M 100000
int main(){
    float a[M],b[M];
    double t1,t2;

    t1=omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp simd
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            a[i]=log(pow(2.71828,(pow(sin(pow(1.1,1.1)),1.1)+1.0))+j);
            b[i]=cos(log(pow(2.71828,pow(sin(pow(1.1,1.1)),1.1)+1.0))+j);
        }
    }
    t2=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elapsed CPU time = %lf seconds.\n",t2-t1);
    printf("simd:a[10] = %f , b[10] = %f \n",a[10],b[10]);
    printf("\n");

    t1=omp_get_wtime();
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            a[i]=log(pow(2.71828,(pow(sin(pow(1.1,1.1)),1.1)+1.0))+j);
            b[i]=cos(log(pow(2.71828,pow(sin(pow(1.1,1.1)),1.1)+1.0))+j);
        }
    }
    t2=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elapsed CPU time = %lf seconds.\n",t2-t1);
    printf("simd:a[10] = %f , b[10] = %f \n",a[10],b[10]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I tried to compile my porgram with intel compiler 2021.6.0:

icc -qopenmp -qopt-report -march=pentium4m 7.c

icc -qopenmp -qopt-report -march=corei7 7.c

icc -qopenmp -qopt-report -march=core-avx2 7.c

icc -qopenmp -qopt-report -march=skylake-avx512 -qopt-zmm-usage=high 7.c

which use MMX, SSE,AVX2 and AVX512 if I am correct.
The MMX works fine. The speedup ratio is 2 (64/32). But the rest of them result in a speedu ratio of 2 4 8.

Shouldn't it be 4, 8 and 16?(128/32, 256/32 and 512/32)

Comment: Note that your code only calculates `log(some_constant+j)` and `cos(some_constant+j)` (you should check what your compiler generates). Then it is hard to say, how well `log` and `cos` vectorize on your machine.

Comment: Changing the architecture has other impact than just changing the SIMD instruction set. AFAIK, MMX was not even able to compute 64-bit double-precision numbers so it should be useless here (at least I cannot find any related instruction in the Intel doc). SSE can (2 lanes). So I guess you use the old FP scalar unit which is completely obsolete since at least 20 years (in fact, also MMX). Besides, most SIMD codes do not perfectly scale. This is not so simple: there are many other parameters to  consider including movs and frequency scaling as well as the number of SIMD units and capabilities

Comment: For example, AVX-512 can be slower on some Skylake processor due to the frequency scaling and only 1 fused SIMD unit. AVX-2 can often speed up code compared to AVX while both are 256-bit wide due to new instructions. The same applies for the FMA unit capable of speeding up a lot FMA operation compared to the old mul+add. Not to mention your code might be memory bound with AVX-512 (possibly due to the limited throughput of each core due to the cache sub-system).

Comment: icc compiler using `-march=pentium4m` and `-march=corei7` options does create exactly the same assembly output (i.e uses xmm registers): https://godbolt.org/z/v99Mzhr14

Comment: @Laci Hi, I looked at the icc doc and it states that pentium4m uses MMX which is 64 bit and corei7 uses SSE4 which is 128 bit. I am so confused about it. Shouldn't SSE4 be 2 times faster than MMX?

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for making it clear. But I still dont get why MMX and SSE4 has the same performance.

Comment: 64-bit processors all have SSE/SSE2 enabled. Thus, the compiler can use this property so to generate a SSE code even if you specify an older architecture not supporting it. AFAIK, there is no 64-bit pentium4m, only 32-bit ones. If you want to test that, you need to compile a 32-bit version but I am not sure this will be simple/possible since 32-bit x86 is now obsolete. I am not sure ICC sill support generating 32-bit programs (at least, ICC clearly does not support 32-bit OS anymore).

Comment: Note that the 32-64 bit switch will certainly have many side effects on the resulting performance (unrelated to the SIMD instruction set). AFAIK, for example the addressing is pretty different in x86 compared to x86-64. Also note that 32-bit programs require 32-bit libraries and so you need a 32-bit libc, 32-bit libmath and so on (transitive). This may require a significant additional space regarding the number of dependencies.